# SQL Aggregate with join giving incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, aggregate

In a bid to learn SQL i've added some dummy data into a few tables that i generated in Excel. I've got a table for customer, order headers and order lines.

Im trying to check that the customers balance, order header total and line totals all match.

But when I run this query I get the incorrect output for the orderheader, i believe it to be becuase its doing the SUM for the amount of times the orderlines table is referenced.

Can anyone tell me the correct way i should be doing it?

```
SELECT 
    cus.cus_id,
    cus.cus_name,
    cus.cus_balance,
    SUM(orderheader.orderheader_currentsell) AS orderHeader_total,
    SUM(orderlines.orderlines_currentsell) AS orderLines_total
FROM
    cus
        JOIN
    orderheader ON orderheader.orderHeader_customer = cus.cus_id
        JOIN
    orderlines ON orderlines.orderlines_orderid = orderheader.orderHeader_id
GROUP BY cus.cus_name
```

output ( the highlighted column should be the same as the other values.)

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple rows for the header.  To solve this, aggregate *before* doing the `join`.  In your case, just aggregating the order lines should be sufficient:

```
SELECT c.cus_id, c.cus_name, c.cus_balance,
    SUM(oh.orderheader_currentsell) AS orderHeader_total,
    SUM(ol.orderLines_total) AS orderLines_total
FROM cus c JOIN
     orderheader oh
     ON oh.orderHeader_customer = c.cus_id JOIN
     (SELECT ol.orderlines_orderid, SUM((ol.orderlines_currentsell) as orderLines_total
      FROM orderlines ol
      GROUP BY ol.orderlines_orderid
     ) ol
     ON ol.orderlines_orderid = oh.orderHeader_id
GROUP BY cus.cus_name;
```

Comment: Its confusing me a bit how this work (it works great by the way).
Can you explain what the select statement in the join is doing. Cant get my head around it for some reason.

Comment: @LewisMorris . . . That is called a subquery or derived table:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have different levels of grouping, it's not that trivial, and you need subselects.

You can calculate the total per customer as a subselect in the field list. In the code below I've done that just for the orders, but you could do the same for the order lines which are still solved by the grouping.

```
SELECT 
    cus.cus_id,
    cus.cus_name,
    cus.cus_balance,
    ( SELECT 
          SUM(orderheader_currentsell) 
      FROM
          orderheader 
      WHERE 
          orderheader.orderHeader_customer = cus.cus_id) AS orderHeader_total,
    SUM(orderlines.orderlines_currentsell) AS orderLines_total
FROM
    cus
JOIN
    orderlines ON orderlines.orderlines_orderid = orderheader.orderHeader_id
GROUP BY cus.cus_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is at first glance, but I am noticing you have:

```
cus.cus_id,
cus.cus_name,
cus.cus_balance,
```

as the non-aggregate columns.  But in your Group-By you only have:

```
GROUP BY cus.cus_name
```

Group By should include all of the non-aggregate columns. This may be why you're not getting the expected results. That would be changed to:

```
GROUP BY cus.cus_id,
         cus.cus_name,
         cus.cus_balance
```